# How to convert perferct date timestamp php?

Tags: php, icalendar

I am creating `ical` calendar event with php. But its generating invalid date time. So, its working in `Outlook` but not working in `iphone`.

Here is my start date: `02/25/2016 9:00 AM`

I am converting it like this:

```
$stamp = strtotime($date_start);
$date_start= gmdate("Ymd\THis",$stamp);
```

and attach Z to it like this,

```
$date_start = $date_start."Z";
```

But it still generates wrong time.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What You expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DateTime` class instead of using `procedural functions`
You can change format however you like.
This one works as you expect:

```
$time = new DateTime('02/25/2016 9:00 AM');
$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));

echo $time->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'));
```

**Result**

```
2016-02-25T09:00:00Z
```

Comment: Do You know main difference between date & gmdate?

Comment: Yes UTC & GMTdifferent time zones. Edited my answer.